# Tensorflow not using GPU (according to TensorBoard)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorboard

edit : GTX 1070, ubuntu 16.04, git hash :
3b75eb34ea2c4982fb80843be089f02d430faade

I am retraining [inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) model on my own data. Everything is fine until the final command :

```
bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train \
  --config=cuda \
  --train_dir="${TRAIN_DIR}" \
  --data_dir="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}" \
  --pretrained_model_checkpoint_path="${MODEL_PATH}" \
  --fine_tune=True \
  --initial_learning_rate=0.001 \
  --input_queue_memory_factor=1
```

According to the logs, **Tensorflow seems to be using the GPU** :

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7715
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.77GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
```

But when I am checking the learning in TensorBoard, **the net is using mainly the CPU** (blue /device:CPU:0, green /device:GPU:0):

TensorBoard graph:

[image: TensorBoard graph]

I have tried this two TensorFlow setups :

1. Install from the source with nvidia-367 drivers, CUDA8 8.0, cuDNN
   v5,    source from the master (16/10/06 - r11?). compiled for GPU
   use:

   ```
   bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
   bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu    
   bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
   ```
2. docker GPU image of Tensorflow on a PC with a GTX
   1070 8Go

   ```
   nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu /bin/bash
   ```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4823) , the inception 'tower' is where the bulk of the work is being performed. So it seems mostly fine.

Except there is still something weird. 
Running `watch nvidia-smi` gives :

Mon Oct 10 10:31:04 2016

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.48                 Driver Version: 367.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 29%   57C    P2    41W / 230W |   7806MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1082    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              69MiB |
|    0      3082    C   /usr/bin/python                               7729MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

While top gives : 

  `PID UTIL.     PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TEMPS+ COM.
 3082 root      20   0 26,739g 3,469g 1,657g S 101,3 59,7   7254:50 python`

GPU seems to be ignored...

Comment: okkkk. At this time, I was running tensorflow from a docker image. It seems `watch nvidia-smi`is not reliable in this case.